# How to add entry in windows "host file" such that it can redirect over https

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect all my browser request to abc.com when a request is sent to xyz.com
I was able to do this by adding an entry in the hosts file under windows.

However I see that i can go to http://abc.com when i type in http://xyz.com:8080
but I cannot seem to get the same redirection over https.

I found out that you cannot mention ports in the host file.
Need some help on this

Comment: @Pekka Can't be done with `https` (hosts have nothing to do with it).

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using the Windows host file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not what the hosts file is for. It's about the **hosts** that you are referring to. `abc.com` and `xyz.com` are hosts.

All the hosts file does is associate a host name with an IP address. Nothing else is possible.

Comment: yup..it seems that we cant even mention port numbers in the host file

Comment: @friction: that's right. Hosts are just machines. The hosts file just maps a host name to an IP address, just like DNS does. Ports are not part of an IP address.

Answer (score 14):

HTTPS is specifically designed so that you *can't* do this - not only is one of the core points of SSL/TLS that the conversation be *encrypted*, it also ensures that you really are talking to who you think you are, that you haven't been redirected to a fake site via DNS.

Comment: ...true, but: that's only related to not being able to get (as in: *buy*) the certificate of `xyz.com` to install that on `abc.com`; it's not a limitation of using the `hosts` file to define specific IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Get a clone of the part you need from the genuine site.. put it on local iis, add ssl binding using self signed certificate and add entry to hosts file.http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com. if you are in rush with no time to play with iis mgr use appcmd.

Youll get a not verified warning for untrusted issuer.. add it to trusted root cert authorities. http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/

Never tried self signed cert tho.. let us now how your testinggoes.

Answer (score 1):

A hosts file is DNS, which is used to resolve a domain name to an IP addresses, which has nothing to do with ports.

If you redirect from https://abc.com to https://xyz.com then they will need to be different servers with different certificates, as an SSL certificate is bound to the domain name.

Which means if you use your hosts file to lookup the ip address of abc.com when you try https://xyz.com then it wont work as the certificate will be for abc.com and wont match the hostheader https://xyz.com sent by your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows command for routing:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=listen_port listenaddress=any_free_ip_address connectport=localhost_port connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

The default port for http request is 80 so if one is using https use 443 as it is the default for https

Comment: More details about this technique can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646749/973425), which makes it possible to not only map IPs but also ports.

Answer (score 0):

With HTTPS, it'll be to do with the security certificate - likely you can't get around that, or at least ... I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

Putting an entry in your hosts file only associates your human readable host name with an ip address, the rest happens in the application that makes http requests.

parts of uri on wikipedia:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/URI_syntax_diagram.svg/1068px-URI_syntax_diagram.svg.png

When ever an application makes a request for a resource, let's say your browser, turns what you type for address into a proper uri, which includes scheme.

If you don't type https, or leave the scheme out, you get http. You end up still getting https for some sites, because they use ssl redirection, maybe something like this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-nginx-reverse-proxy-https-wss-self-signed-ramos-da-silva/?articleId=6678584723419226112

Answer (score -2):

Use nslookup xyz.com and get IP

then put this IP to hosts (/etc/hosts in Linux)

the https domain name must transform to IP from

Comment: I think the redirect can be done only via Apache httpd.conf. Your solution might not be feasible here. If you think it is, please be more descriptive.