# Access localhost:3000 through mysite.loc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

When I'm on my development laptop, I want to go to the URL "mysite.loc" instead of "localhost:3000" for a particular project. How can I do this?

I am using Ruby on Rails 4, and the default WEBrick server.

I have tried adding "127.0.0.1 mysite.loc" to my /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Short answer is you need to install `phusion passenger` and configure it to listen port `3000` to ysite.loc

Comment: Do any of the 4 default servers that Rails comes with not work?

Comment: I'm not expert of configuring web servers but if you are not familiar with `phusion passenger` I think the "port forwarding" will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people suggest installing [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Add your local sitename to the HOSTS file then add a custom rule to Fiddler.

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {  
  if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "mysite.loc") { 
    oSession.host = "mysite.loc:3000";
  }
}
```

Then when you navigate to `http://mysite.loc` it should be proxied to `http://mysite.loc:3000`.

Related questions: 
  [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/115282/can-i-configure-the-windows-hosts-file-to-use-ip-address-plus-port)
  [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-on-windows-xp-host-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a definition to your /etc/hosts file, but you will still have to use port 3000 in the URL, unless you also change this to the HTTP default (80). You could, if you really wanted, just run on port 80

```
sudo rails s -p 80
```

Not that binding to port 80 generally requires su privilege - hence the use of sudo (if available).

If you want to get straight to the desired result, with the assistance of some programming magic there is

http://pow.cx/

It does some local DNS and port magic to let you do what you are wanting.