# IIS 8 Dummy Host Name is not working correctly

Tags: .net, iis, windows-8.1, hosts, iis-8.5

There is many answers on the issue I am looking for but most of them are on IIS 7 or earlier and nothing worked for me for some reason, so here it goes.

I am trying to add some dummy host names to test my project locally, what I did is editing the hosts file with the fake domain names like below

```
127.0.0.1        44336     Whatever.com
127.0.0.1        44336     SSOWhatever.Whatever.com
```

Then I have changed my IIS bindings to for each project to the correct one with  the correct port, but this fail to work. what is confusing me even more is that when I remove .com (all the dots have to be removed) so if my file look like below:

```
127.0.0.1        44336     Whatever
127.0.0.1        44336     SSOWhatever
```

This works fine but, it is not simulating what I want. any ideas why this is happening is there something I need to set in the IIS.

Comment: Please elaborate on "fail to work". What happens when you set the binding's host name to `SSOWhatever.Whatever.com`?

Comment: on chrome get this error `This web page is not available` and on IE `This page can’t be displayed`

Comment: Since when does windows host file support ports?

Comment: I am assuming since IIS6 because I think I got the idea of ports from here https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true I also saw loads of question and answers here with the same hosts file

Comment: Well - it's just wrong or is not true anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file

Comment: I am really not sure I can say this is true because it sure working for me to some extent. actually if I removed the port is failing because I am assuming it is listening to 80 and nothing is there.

Comment: What prevents you of typing whatever.com:44336 in your browser? You don't need this in the hosts file (and as I said - it's not supported)

Comment: ahh now I see what you mean yea you are right, but that doesn't answer my main question or solve my problem. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have some mismatches here:

- The host file is in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\
- The host file does not have any intelligence and supports Host to IP Mappings only
- The mappings have to be exact: someHost.com will not match www.someHost.com
- The mappings have the form *IPAdress* *Hostname* - there is no support for ports
- Check that your IIS bindings match to the exact same strings and are bound to all IP addresses or the localhost IP address

If everything is correct you can access your application by typing *http(s)://hostname:port*

You can also use fiddler for that - the program is also able to do port redirections - and on the plus side you can see the requests for debugging.

Comment: I gave this the correct answer not because I have a mismatch but your tip on using fiddler, helped me to know the issue is my company proxy interfering. so anyone who land on this page and you are just not understanding why it is not working just check your proxy rules to eliminate one of the reasons, or in my case the main reason. Thanks!!