# Developing node.js locally on windows, how can I point localhost:1337 to use my own URL like mywebsite.local?

Tags: node.js, localhost, sails.js

I am very new to node, and just trying to start building an app in the sails framework.

I would like to point http://mywebsite.local to the sails app on localhost:1337 if possible?

I have added an entry to the windows hosts file as such:

127.0.0.1:1337      mywebsite.local

Thanks

Comment: You can modify your hosts file to solve the name part.  Changing the port redirection is not possible as far as I know unless your use a proxy server or change the default port your browser uses.

Comment: This answer might help as well (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file)

Comment: The [sails gitter room](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails) is also a good place to chat.

Comment: See the answer with netsh in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file