# Unable to run PHP, MySQL, Apache and NetBeans (all with the latest versions as of 2016)

Tags: java, php, mysql, apache, netbeans

Originally default configuration done.

Apache and SQL starting error with conflict of port usage with skype
initially 
changed in skype.
after a day once again some issue.
    so changed in config in Apache / httpd.conf 
Change made to port

```
#listen  80
listen 10080'
# ServerName localhost:80
ServerName localhost:10080

Similarly change to apache / httpd.ssl

# Listen 443
Listen 10443

# ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerName www.example.com:10443
# <VirtualHost _default_:443>
<VirtualHost _default_:10443>
```

[image: Error page when I try to run the PHP file through NetBeans]

Also, what does this mean? What should I do to get rid of this error?

[image: Where I think the problem lies... But if it is, not sure what to do to correct it...]

Answer (score 0):

Now your Apache Server is working, but you wanted to call a file which doesnt' exist at this location, please check for typos.  By the way, if you change port to  10080 you'll have to use URL like this: `localhost:10080`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! :D:D:D but how to make it default? instead of typing that out everytime... Like how to make it run automatically at localhost:10080?

Comment: If you want to do something like this, you'll have to use 3rd party software, e.g. Fiddler 2. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file) for more information

Comment: I managed to do it without using 3rd party software. It worked when I changed the local properties of the project in NetBeans. Anyways, thanks a lot!!! :D