# Is it possible to run VueJS dev server without port?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

When I write `npm run dev` it starts on `http://localhost:8080`

Is it possible run on `http://testdomain.local/`? (without port)

Comment: Vue is using webpack which is using express as their dev server. As far as I am concerned webpack always has to listen to a specific port, but you could remap your desired domain in your operating system's host file to the localhost address.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file