# How to config domain for Adonisjs project?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, adonis.js

Simple when run npm run dev, adonisjs will run with domain:

> http://localhost:3333

But i wanna config with domain:

> http://blog.com
>   http://blog.local

Please help me!!!

Comment: You own these domains? or you just want for local development?

Comment: What has this got to with Apache and nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear but I'll try to answer.

1. If you are trying to get those domain names on your development machine, take a look at this: http://adonisjs.com/recipes/4.0/dev-domains
2. If you are trying to host your Adonis app on a server, take a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

If you are in development environment or local machine there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file)

But if your are in production environment you should install and config BIND9 or something like that to work as DNS Server but there is an alternative and simple solution:

Firstly register on http://cloudflare.com and add your domain on your dashboard. then it gives your two DNS you should set to your domain. then in the cloudflare dashboard create a **A Record** to point your domain to your server **IP**

Then install Nginx on your server to work as a **Reverse Proxy** and use this config to point your domain to your awesome adonisjs project:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Spinning up a CDN and mapping DNS addresses is MASSIVE overkill for simply getting a site online. Running a DNS server is irrelevant.