# Docker mapping ports and expose to specific hosts

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, gitlab, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running Docker locally. I'm testing some functions from Jenkins and GitLab, so I ran:

For Jenkins:

```
docker run -d \
--add-host="gitlab.example.com:172.16.2.92" \
-p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
--name jenkins \
--restart always \
-v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

For GitLab:

```
docker run --detach \
--hostname gitlab.example.com \
--publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 23:22 \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

I don't have any problem exposing ports and accessing to the containers.

**My problem**

Both containers runs locally, my IP is 192.168.x.x and added GitLab's host to my hosts file, so when I try to access to GitLab, no problem. I type gitlab.example.com in the browser and vuola, GitLab's main page. I try to do the same with Jenkins adding host to docker.

```
docker run -d \
--hostname jenkins.example.com \
--add-host="gitlab.example.com:172.16.2.92" \
-p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
--name jenkins \
--restart always \
-v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

But I don't have any idea how to add the URL to my hosts file. I tried to add 192.168.x.x:8080 and jenkins.example.com but nothing. If I type jenkins.example.com in the browser nothing happends.

I found thta I can use nginx to do that *binding* but is not clear for me.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current problem that you are facing is:
Check this article : [Port numbers are not a valid part in hosts file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file)

Now to overcome this issue and to solve it you can define two different hostnames to the same IP and then use Apache HTTP proxy server and define different routes to forward your requests to different destinations.

Take reference for httpd : [Apache httpd](https://nitstorm.github.io/blog/apache-forward-reverse-proxies-1/)

Comment: Great answer!! Thanks!! Now I'm going to try to solve my problem with this.