# asp.net mvc publish on windows without key word localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to publish asp.net MVC web application on my windows laptop
and I want to access published web application with my customized URL 
which not contained localhost keyword.

I tried it a lot but there are 2 problems:

1) I am not able to access the published site

2) If I publish as localhost I can reach my web application [Which I don't want]

Comment: This is not a question. Try it by yourself and if you encounter any problems ask a 
specific question. Describing what you tried and what your problem is.

Comment: i try it alot but still keyword local host exists

Comment: so my question how to do it with my custom url on my local machine

Comment: @FatmaTolba yes you can do this, Have you heard about IIS Server? Or familiar with IIS Server?

Comment: yes i know it but also it not accept any word and give me can't reach

Comment: @FatmaTolba [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRcQq8U4WbY) is a sample demo, you just understand and work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Publish your site normally on IIS
2. Go to C:windows/system32/drivers/etc/
3. Open the hosts file with notepad
4. Go to the end of the last line and hit Enter, then add the following line

   127.0.0.1 fatma.com
5. Save the file. Note: If Save As dialog shows up, choose another directory. Change Save as type to All Files. Press Save. Replace the hosts file in C:windows/system32/drivers/etc/ with this one.
6. Open your browser and type fatma.com
   This will open your localhost site. If you published your site on a different port for example 8090, you can reach your site by fatma.com:8090 

   For more information check [this](https://bowerwebsolutions.com/how-to-edit-your-local-host-file-for-testing-web-sites/) .

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working but i want to hide port number how can i do that ?

Comment: Simply publish your site on port 80.

Comment: But if you want to keep your port, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646749/4604881)