# How to change the localhost:8080 to www.myWebApp.com?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Every time I access my spring boot application I type `localhost:8080`.
I want to access the application by typing www.MyApp.com. It is an in-house application so it is not going to be live on the Web. The application is using spring boot embedded. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Does your hosts file contain a line like "127.0.0.1  www.MyApp.com"?

Comment: How you access your application isn't generally related to anything in app's configuration itself. Generally speaking, address of your application isn't actually the `localhost` - it's a `127.0.0.1:8080`, localhost name is being just a common name resolved by your browser to mean `127.0.0.1`. For most things on the web, we use DNS servers to convert from human-readable address to machine readable one. For an in-house app, you have to imitate a DNS service yourself, locally. In Windows, that can be done by editing the hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

This is more related to operating system's host configurations.

https://www.webhosting.uk.com/kb/how-to-update-hosts-file-entry-on-windows-ubuntu-and-mac/

About the adding port number in host file
refer: [Using port number in Windows host file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file)