# How to get local development .test domains working with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, hosts

With Rails and puma-dev I can easily have multiple projects on my dev machine running on different hosts e.g.

```
~/development/myapp => http://myapp.test
~/development/myapp2 => http://myapp2.test
~/development/myapp3 => http://myapp3.test
```

With NodeJS (NextJS etc.) it is

```
~/development/myapp => http://localhost:3000
~/development/myapp2 => http://localhost:3001
~/development/myapp3 => http://localhost:3003
```

And I have to manually run `npm run dev` for each.

How do I get similar functionality to Rails and puma-dev please?

I have tried to edit /etc/hosts but am not clear on how to avoid having a port in the URL e.g. I don't want http://myapp.test:3000 nor do I want to run `npm run dev` on port 80 or 8080.

Comment: You might be able to use Fiddler if you're on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file#answer-21586034

Comment: @Bryan — I don't see Fiddler starting services on demand

Comment: if you're using a linux machine, you could use nginx server to proxy your localhost. If you're using windows, I don't see how possible.
if you really need to get rid of the port, you could try ngrok, which gives you a public url

https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0):

Puma-dev is hooking into ports 80/443 by default. This is also where you computer/browser/host happens to look. (i.e. a request to http://localhost is automatically going to look at port 80/http and 443/https).

If you want this behavior for NextJS, you can put it behind an nginx proxy (http OR https).

To apply the behavior you're looking for in puma, `echo 3000 > ~/.puma-dev/myapp`

From puma-dev docs (https://github.com/puma/puma-dev?tab=readme-ov-file#proxy-support):

Proxy support
Puma-dev can also proxy requests from a nice dev domain to another app. To do so, just write a file (rather than a symlink'd directory) into ~/.puma-dev with the connection information.

For example, to have port 9292 show up as awesome.test: echo 9292 > ~/.puma-dev/awesome.

Or to proxy to another host: echo 10.3.1.2:9292 > ~/.puma-dev/awesome-elsewhere.

Comment: There is an issue in puma-dev (https://github.com/puma/puma-dev/issues/252) that explains that to use this with the proxy, you must use the full host/protocal and all. 

`echo "http://localhost:3000" > ~/.pum-dev/myapp`