# How to forward all requests on port X to localhost (Windows)

Tags: windows, localhost, portforwarding

I need to forward all requests on port 200 to localhost:8080.

Here is what I tried, but I need more direction actually getting it to work. If there is a more obvious way (firewall?, browser's proxy settings?) please say.

1. **netsh** as admin

   ```
   netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=+ listenport=200 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=8080 protocol=tcp
   ```

   This did not work for me (requests to :200 time out) whether I use `*` or `+` as listenaddress.
2. **Local proxy**.
   Many options exist, but cannot find docs that deal with port forwarding for any of them. Spent lots of time with Acrylic but my experiments all failed. Pointers to docs or actual rules would help loads.

   - [Acrylic](https://mayakron.altervista.org)
   - [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org) (formerly JunkBusters)
   - [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (referred to [on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21586034), but not current)
   - [Ergo](https://github.com/cristianoliveira/ergo) (or perhaps [Ergo](https://github.com/ont/ergo)?)
   - [Proximodo](http://proximodo.sourceforge.net) (formerly proxomitron. Abandoned?)
   - [Karma](https://github.com/arantius/karma-blocker) (abandoned?)
3. **Browser Plugins**.
   I am sure there are some, but cannot find any. Installed uMatrix and spent an hour understanding its rules before realizing that it cannot do this at all.
4. **External Port Forwarding**, with the router or Pi-Hole.
   I don't have piHole, and am using a no-name router provided and locked by my local ISP. I could probably ask them to open it, but is that worth pursuing?
5. **VPN software**.
   I would guess that there is VPN software that has routing options. Not sure, and wouldn't know where to start.

Please advise!

Comment: Do you not have access to *Port Forwarding* option on your ISP's router settings?

Comment: I do not. (When I go to the IP address of the router it asks for a password.) Is that easy to setup, assuming the ISP would allow me in?

Comment: I'm not sure about USA, but at least in Europe, the default user and password comes on a label, on the back of the router. (E.g. https://www.tp-link.com/resources/images/faq/2008410143049281.jpg)

First time you log in, you change the password (and possibly the user too).