# How to get code from Sign in with Apple in Unity when redirect urls localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not permitted

Tags: unity-game-engine, redirect, oauth-2.0, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to implement Sign in with Apple in the Unity editor. I am doing this using the REST API oauth flow. In my other oauth implementations I have been able to set a valid redirect url as localhost, so I can catch the response in the app with a http listener. However, Apple does not allow this address, not 127.0.0.1 . How can I get the response code back in Unity? Sign in with Apple is so new that I have not been able to find any answers so far. All of the guides are for implementing Sign in in a web client, not an app.

Comment: It sounds like the redirect address has to be one reachable for Apple, so routed in the web?

Comment: You need to be able to validate your `redirect_uri` while creating a Service ID and for Apple to be able to verify your given address it needs to be a live website which is reachable from the internet.

Answer (score 8):

Open etc/hosts file and add record to it

127.0.0.1 mylocaladdr.test

Use the following redirect uri address instead of localhost:

http://Mylocaladdr.test/appleredirect

Add other real domain and verify it. Add real redirect uri, which later will be used.

Comment: You can also try Fiddler2 if you want to redirect for some specific port on your local machine.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21586034/9307598