# "Local by flywheels" and "local web server" conflicting ports on Mac Catalina

Tags: wordpress, localhost, port, local, macos-catalina

I am macOS Catalina and got my local webserver running following this [article](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250001766).
And then I installed Local by Flywheel but am unable to use the Router Mode: Site Domains due to port conflicts.

It is inconvenient for my local WordPress sites to be localhost:30001 instead of sitename.dev.
Is there a way to have both local by flywheels and the local server working together?

My host file is

```
> ##
> # Host Database
> #
> # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
> # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
> ##
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 255.255.255.255   broadcasthost ::1   localhost
> 
> ## Local by Flywheel - Start ## ::1 www.helpneeded.dev #Local Site
> 127.0.0.1 www.helpneeded.dev #Local Site
> ## Local by Flywheel - End ##
```

The local webserver is also using port 80.

Error Seen on Local Panel - Port Conflict:

[image: error description]

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `sitename.dev:30001`, but if you really wanted to, there is a workaround at [Using port number in Windows host file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file) that you can use. The workaround uses `netsh` which manages network interface and is able to create a proxy on the network interface allowing you to forward traffic without actually having to bind to a specific port first. Combine that with the fact that everything in 127.x.x.x refers to yourself, and you just need to add `127.0.0.2 sitename.dev` to your hosts file, and then use the workaround to forward `127.0.0.2:80` -> `127.0.0.1:3001`.

See also [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)